# XNA draw a rectangle 3D perpendicular to camera

Tags: xna, .net, rendertexture

I need some ideas how to implement the `Draw` method.

Need to draw a rectangle (actually a million of them, all same texture) that is in 3D, starts at point `p` and ends at point `q` and is always perpendicular to the camera. So, it is impossible for me to go around it and see how flat it really is. The points `p` and `q` are marked on the texture.

[image]

Comment: In your place I would make that leaf texture smaller, I can tell you, that no one is going to look at it from closer than 0.1 units

Comment: I would advise you to not use XNA, because it is entirely discontinued.

Comment: What else would you recommend on Windows to draw textured rectangles?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done many ways, here I'll give you non language or engine specific answers.

The first way to do it is useful, if you don't want to or can't use shaders, you need to [get the angles of the vector](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/159883-converting-a-3D-vector-into-three-euler-angles) that goes from the object to the camera and set the angles of the rectangle to the results. If you have a `lookAt` function by any chance, then just use that to make the object look at the camera.

The second solution works if you create shaders, and is way more effective, because the CPU is not the most well suited for these kinds of operations.

When you move the vertex in the vertex shader, you usually multiply it with a modelview matrix (if you have a separate model and view matrix, just multiply them together in the view -> model order). If you look at how the rotations are coded in this matrix:

[image]

you can see that the rotations utilize the top-left 3x3 area of the 4x4 matrix. To remove rotations, you need to set these to

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

Then you can use the resulted matrix.

Comment: BTW, I looked it up, and yes, [XNA does have a lookAt function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195650.aspx). Use the resulting matrix as a rotation matrix, and to get the model matrix, just multiply it with the scale and the translation matrices